# Position image with css so that it will not create the horizontal scroolbar from browser

Tags: html, css, image

i`m trying to create something similar to this: http://www.solidstudio.it/ notice the earth image ( world_black.png ) is absolutely positioned to the right, but even if i have small browser window width, it will not create the horizontal scrool bar. How can something like this be achieved ? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `overflow-x:hidden` to your body:

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the overflow property.

overflow: hidden;

This should hide the content that is outside the designated area without showing a scrollbar.